# SQL select from 2 tables with specific queries

Tags: sql, relational-database

I'm learning SQL and I wanted to select a certain list of names and telephone numbers for a certain ID number. These names are names of customers who bought Furniture with FurnitureID. This list also should be presented in alphabetical order of the names of the customers. I'm not sure how Join works and how I could also list it in alphabetical order of the customers names.

So a customer places an order at the store and the company then orders the furniture required from its suppliers. When the ordered furniture arrives at the store a member of staff telephones or emails the customer to inform them that it is ready for collection. Customers often order more than one type of furniture on the same order, for example a sofa and two chairs.

The tables are stored in a relational database:

- Furniture(*FurnitureID*, FurnitureName, Category, Price, SupplierName)
- CustomerOrder(*OrderID*, CustomerID, Date)
- CustomerOrderLine(*OrderID*, *FurnitureID*, Quantity)
- Customer(*CustomerID*, CustomerName, EmailAddress, TelephoneNumber)

What I've done so far is:

```
SELECT Furniture.FurnitureID, Customer.CustomerName, Customer.TelephoneNumber) 
FROM Furniture, Customer 
WHERE FurnitureID = 10765
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `exists` condition with a correlated subuqery to filter the `Customer` table for those who ordered the concerned furniture:

```
select c.CustomerName, c.TelephoneNumber
from customer c
where exists (
    select 1
    from CustomerOrder co
    inner join CustomerOrderLine col
        on  col.OrderID = co.OrderID
        and col.FurnitureID = ?
    where co.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
)
order by c.CustomerName
```

The question mark (`?`) represents the id of the furniture that you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select c.* From Customer c inner join CustomerOrder co on c.CustomerID co.CustomerID
inner join CustomerOrderLine col on col.OrderID = co.OrderID
inner join Furniture f on f.FurnitureID = col.FurnitureID
where f.FurnitureID = 10765
order by CustomerName
```